# Cannot sort foreign keys fields in django admin list

Tags: django, sorting, django-admin, foreign-keys

I'm trying to sort foreign keys in the change list but it is not working yet. (I have seen that when clicking for sorting in the table, it gets wrong when foreign keys)

```
class ProductVariantAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    fields=["product", "test_software", "test_variables", "name", "description"]
    list_display = ("name", "product", "test_software", "test_variables", "description")
    search_fields = ["name"]
    form = ProductVariantForm

    def formfield_for_foreignkey(self, db_field, request, **kwargs):
        print db_field.name
        if db_field.name == "test_software_id":
            kwargs["queryset"] = TestSoftware.objects.all().order_by('name')
        return super(ProductVariantAdmin, self).formfield_for_foreignkey(db_field, request, **kwargs)
```

I have seen that they work with the formfield_for_foreignkey, but i get still the list sorted by the id and not by the name of the foreign key.

Any solution to that? I'm using django 1.4.1.

Answer (score 2):

`formfield_for_foreignkey` only overrides the drop down menu.

What you probably want is to order in the model's `Meta`:

```
 class TestSoftware(models.Model):
      class Meta:
           ordering = ['name']
```

Comment: in fact, it is not about the drop down menu, but the change list that appears in the beginning. when sorting by clicking the header columns, it doesn't work

Comment: Yes. Which is why you should be adding `ordering` on the foreign model you want sorted.